# C# Is there a way to exclude a member from serialization dynamically?

Tags: c#, serialization, dynamic

C# Is there a way to exclude a member from serialization dynamically?

e.g. (I make up this code, not real)

class def:

```
[Serializable]
public class Class1
{
    public int Property1{get;set;}
}
```

and I do

```
Class1 c=new Class(){Property1=15};
SerializationOption option = new SerializationOption(){ExludeList=new List(){"Property1"}};
var result=Serialize(Class1,option);
```

Comment: is adding an attribute not an option? E.g. `[XmlIgnore]public int Property1 { get; set; }`

Comment: This isn't XmlSerialization, it's .Net serialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to control this is to implement `ISerializable` on the class and have access to some context during serialization. For example:

```
public class Class1 : ISerializable
{ 
    // ....
    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        var excludeList = (List<String>)context.Context;

        if(!excludeList.Contains("Property1"))
        {
            info.AddValue("Property1",Property1);
        }
    }
}
```

You provide this context during creating of the formatter. For example:

```
var sc = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All, 
                              new List<String> { "Property1" });
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter(null, sc);
```